# DP: find minimum time and print operations of calculator

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

My task is different from another questions dedicated to "primitive calculator" problem.
You are given a primitive calculator that can perform the following three operations with the current number x: multiply x by 2(for time b), multiply x by 3(for time c), or add 1 to x(for time a). Your goal is given a positive integer n, find the minimum time needed to obtain the number n starting from the 0, and also print operations to obtain the number in this format:
x + 1 "add"
x * 2 "double"
x * 3 "triple"

```
Sample Input:

25 1 4 5
```

```
Sample Output:

14
add
add
add
add
triple
double
add
```

First steps should be obvious(we have 0 at start, and 1st operation will be "add" in any case(bc 0 * 2 = 0 and 0 * 3 = 0):

```
input_data = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
n = input_data[0]
a = input_data[1]
b = input_data[2]
c = input_data[3]
def primitive_calc(n):
    oper = []
    time = []
    oper[0] = "add"
    time[0] = a
```

But after then ... I don't know how to set up x+1,x*2,x*3 in my case. Saving time shouldn't be a problem(appending a,b,c in list and sum(time) as result). But how to save operations?
Please, don't write exact solution, instead give me ideas and hints. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to build a dynamic solution. For the current number, you need to pick a possible state that takes minimum time to reach the target

Comment: What is the maximum size (n) of the problem ? A simple iterative solution can give a solution with O(n) complexity. Is it good enough?

Comment: Yes, DP approach is the only good option. But my primary question was how to implement this steps(x+1,x*2,x*3) in code. About complexity...sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

A simple iterative implementation can provide a solution with O(n) complexity.

Let us call `T[i]` the minimum time to arrive at level `i`. Then,

```
T[i+1] <= T[i] + a
T[2*i] <= T[i] + b
T[3*i] <= T[i] + c
```

Concerning the path to follow in order to get the minimum time, it is enough at each step to memorise the choice `S[i]` that lead to `T[i]`

Then a possible iterative implementation is:

**Initialisation**

```
T[i] = infinite
T[1] = a
S[i] = Null
S[1] = add
```

**Iteration**

```
Do i = 2 to n-1
    T[i+1] = min(T[i+1], T[i] + a) -> if min obtained, S[i+1] = add
    T[2*i] = min(T[i+1], T[i] + b) -> if min obtained, S[2*i] = double
    T[3*i] = min(T[i+1], T[i] + c) -> if min obtained, S[3*i] = triple
```

**Output**

```
Min cost = T[n]
Path: use the S[i] from S[n] in reverse order
```

Comment: hmmm,looking good. I will try your idea, thank you! If more questions occur, I will publish them.